# Any API to get top accessed sites

Tags: search, bing

Any API to get most accessed sites on internet.I have tried looking at Google API's but they are limited for private domain.I am trying to know is there any API to access most visited sites on internet

or

Is there any API where we can access top searches made on the internet

Answer (score 0):

There is Alexa, they offer an API with shich you should be able to achieve this  http://aws.amazon.com/awis/

Comment: Will look into it.Can you please update me if you find ay other API's .Please update the same POST.